# Creating a plugin/component that will filter incoming emails on an exchange server?

Tags: email, exchange-server

Is there a predefined protocol / API that will allow me to create a plugin component for exchange (let's say 2007+)?

I need to write a simple spam filter that will communicate with the exchange server and receive every mail that is received by that server. If the mail doesn't pass a check, it will be deleted from the server before being delivered to the user. If it is ok, it will be placed in the user's inbox.

I am looking for a protocol that supports the following:

1. subscribe to receive a notification whenever an email arrives to the server (before the email is placed in the users' in-box.
2. get the content of such emails.
3. have the ability to block further processing on some emails (so they are blocked before reaching the inbox).

Thanks in advance,

Answer (score 1, accepted):

May be u can write a transport agent(Exchange Server 2007onwards) which will monitor and act on  all the emails flowing through the organisation.

You can get most of the details of an email via a transport agent depending on the event at which u trigger the agent.

Here's a link which gives a thorough  documentation.

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/exchange/bb204097(v=exchg.150).aspx

You can check body/subject and if it doesn't comply with any of the organisational policy,just clear off all the recipients and the email delivery won't happen.